# What is wrong with this Queue Class? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my Que class,  but am not that versed with objects, so getting the size and elements of the object is not working for me

```
class Queue{
   // Array is used to implement a Queue
    constructor(){
        this.items = {};
        this.count = 0;
    }

    // enqueue(item)
    enqueue(element){    
        // adding element to the queue
        this.items.push(element);
        this.count++;
    }
    // dequeue()
    dequeue(){
        // removing element from the queue
        // returns underflow when called 
        // on empty queue
        if(this.isEmpty())
            return "Underflow";
        this.count--;
        return this.items.shift();
     }

    // front()
    front(){
        // returns the Front element of 
        // the queue without removing it.
        if(this.isEmpty())
            return "No elements in Queue";
        return this.items[0];
    }
```

// isEmpty()

```
    isEmpty(){
        // return true if the queue is empty.
        return this.items.length == 0;
    }

    // peek()
    peek(){
        return this.items[this.count]
    }

    size(element){
        return this.count;
    }

    show(){
        var result = '';
        var i=this.count-1;

        for(i; i>=0; i--){
            result += this.items[i] +' ';
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Methods like size(), show(), and isEmpty() are not working?
they are returning undefined.

Comment: Did you realize that `items` is not an array?

Answer (score 1):

Small mistake in your code. Just change the object literal to array literal for items. `this.items = []`

```js
class Queue{
   // Array is used to implement a Queue
    constructor(){
        this.items = []; //the problem is resolved
        this.count = 0;
    }

    // enqueue(item)
    enqueue(element){    
        // adding element to the queue
        this.items.push(element);
        this.count++;
    }
    // dequeue()
    dequeue(){
        // removing element from the queue
        // returns underflow when called 
        // on empty queue
        if(this.isEmpty())
            return "Underflow";
        this.count--;
        return this.items.shift();
     }

    // front()
    front(){
        // returns the Front element of 
        // the queue without removing it.
        if(this.isEmpty())
            return "No elements in Queue";
        return this.items[0];
    }
    
    // isEmpty()
    isEmpty(){
        // return true if the queue is empty.
        return this.items.length == 0;
    }

    // peek()
    peek(){
        return this.items[this.count]
    }

    size(element){
        return this.count;
    }

    show(){
        var result = '';
        var i=this.count-1;

        for(i; i>=0; i--){
            result += this.items[i] +' ';
        }

        return result;
    }
}

let q = new Queue();

console.log(q.isEmpty())
console.log(q.size())
console.log(q.show());
```

Answer (score 0):

1st, you are threatening items like if it is an array, but you declare it as an object of any type. 
2nd, when you call the size function, could be a better approach return: items.length.
and last, you can remove the count variable from each of its usages now.

Good luck.